# Promise in Javascript -- code is still loads synchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, promise

I'm creating a script that can be added to each html page to load the navigation bar from one file called template-html.txt.

This can allow me to modify only the nav template and have all the pages update.

Inside the HTML of the navbar, each page has to manually define the "value" attribute for the option tags since the url is unique to the page and cannot be put in the template:

```
<select id="lang" onchange="countryHandler(this.value)" class="form-select" style="width: 50%;">
          <option id="english" value=""> English</option>
          <option id="francais"value="">Français</option>
</select>
```

The problem I ran into is that the script to set the values of #english and #french would run before the html was loaded, so it couldn't update the values.

To fix that, I tried implementing promises, but the code still appears to run synchronously:

```
window.addEventListener("load", setLang);
var p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    
//adds nav tag
    $("body").prepend("<nav id='ajax'></nav>");
//ajax call to get template-html.txt
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var htmlLoaded = 0;
    xhr.open('GET', 'template-html.txt');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        //console.log(`state changed: ${xhr.readyState}`);

        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
//append html to nav
            $("nav#ajax").append(xhr.responseText);
            htmlLoaded = 1;
            console.log(`html loaded status:${htmlLoaded} `);
        }
    }
    xhr.send();

    console.log(`second html loaded status:${htmlLoaded} `);
    if (htmlLoaded == 1) {
        resolve("it's resolved");
        console.log("it's resolved")
    } else {
        reject();
        console.log("it's rejected")
    }
});



function setLang() {
//promise that ONLY once the html has loaded you will access and change the value of the option tag
    p
        .then(function () {
            $("#english").val("./FAQ");
            console.log($('#english').val());
            $("#francais").val("./fr/FAQ");
        })
        .catch(console.log('the function failed'));

}
```

When I run this code, the navbar loads, but the values aren't added in the option tags leading me to believe the jQuery is running before the AJAX request has finished handling.
This seems to be confirmed by the "second html status:0" coming up before the "first html status:1" as shown in the console log below:
[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/API52.png)

```
second html loaded status:0 

nav.js:25 

it's rejected

VM20003:2 Nav.js

nav.js:14 first html loaded status:1 

nav.js:38 the function failed

FAQ.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) undefined
```

I'm still learning about promises, so any help is mega appreciated!

Comment: You're calling `resolve()` and `reject()` at the wrong place. Remember, the XHR is complete only inside the `.onreadystatechange` function so you must call `resolve()` inside that function

Comment: The `if (htmlLoaded == 1)` code still runs before the XHR callback function, so yo're resolving/rejecting immediately. The place to do that is in the XHR callback function. That aside: consider using `fetch` or Axios or something reasonable.